# Why use immutable Vector or String in Rust

Tags: rust, immutability

I'm learning Rust and learned, that for making an expandable string or array, the `String` and `Vec` structs are used. And to modify a `String` or `Vec`, the corresponding variable needs to be annotated with `mut`.

```
let mut myString = String::from("Hello");
let mut myArray = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

My question is, why would you use or declare an immutable `String` or `Vec` like

```
let myString = String::from("Hello");
let myArray = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

instead of a true array or str literal like

```
let myString = "Hello";
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
```

What would be the point of that, does it have any benefits? And what may be other use cases for immutable `String`'s and `Vec`'s?

**Edit:**

Either I am completely missing something obvious or my question isn't fully understood. I get why you want to use a mutable `String` or `Vec` over the str literal or an array, since the latter are immutable. But why would one use an immutable `String` or `Vec` over the str literal or the array (which are also immutable)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Rust's \`String\` and \`str\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)

Comment: By the way, the type name is `Vec` and not `Vector`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between \[\], &\[\], and vec!\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848114/what-are-the-differences-between-and-vec)

Comment: If the string isn't known at compile time, it must be stored somewhere. You can't own a `str`. `String` is a convenient solution to own a string when you need a `&str`.

Comment: Important: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698 ; That the value of type `String` or `Vec` is behind an immutable variable does not necessarily mean that its value will never be modified: it could be moved into a new context where it will.

Comment: @Herohtar no, because in he explains '[use `Vec` ...] in order to be able to change its size during runtime'. But if the `Vec` variable is immutable, is there any other reason to use `Vec`?

Comment: @Smitop that somewhat answers the question but not completely. He states that you use `String` 'when you need to own or modify your string data'. That's what I was looking for. If I don't want to modify my string data (i. e. not annotated with `mut`), the other reason to use `String` is when I want to own the string data. Why would I want to do that?

Comment: @DenysSéguret could you elaborate on that? Why would I want to own a `String` instead of `&str` bound to a variable?

Comment: @Codey A `&str` is a reference to some other place in memory. This place must exist. If the string isn't static, the easiest solution is to reference a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You might then do something with that string, for example use it to populate a struct:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    field: String,
}

...

let s = String::from("hello");
let mut mystruct = MyStruct { field: s };
```

You could also, for example, return it from a function.

Comment: Yes but I could use the `str` literal for this as well right? Are there any advantages of using this immutable `String` vs. the `str` literal in this case?

Comment: You could use a &'static str as well, but only if MyStruct will never mutate `field`. If you're never going to mutate them, then there's no reason to use a String or Vec.

Comment: Ok I understand, this is a very good example. With your implementation I could still modify the string with `mystruct.field.push_str(" world")` even though `s` is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

One use case could be the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let text: [u8; 6] = [0x48, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x4c, 0x4f, 0x00];
    let converted = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(text.as_ptr() as *const c_char) }.to_string_lossy().to_string();

    println!("{}", converted);
}
```

This is a bit constructed, but imagine you want to convert a null terminated C string (which might come from the network) from a raw pointer to some Rust string, but you don't know whether it has invalid UTF-8 in it. `to_string_lossy()`  returns a `Cow`  which *either* points to the original bytes (in case everything is valid UTF-8), but if that's not the case, it will basically copy the string and do a new allocation, replace the invalid characters with the UTF-8 replacement character and then point to that.

This is of course quite nice, because (presumably) most of the time you get away without copying the original C string, but in some cases, it might not be. But if you don't care about that and don't want to work with a `Cow`, it might make sense to convert it to a `String`, which you don't need to be mutable afterwards. But it's not possible to have a `&str` in case the original text contains invalid UTF-8.